# remove images while exporting excel from gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

[image]

I am exporting excel from gridview and it is not giving me good format. Images are showing on excel file. I don't want the images, what can I do?

here is my code

```
protected void Export_to_Excel(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=vault-extract-nsf.xls");
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xlsx";
    System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
    GridView1.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
    Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: you can replace image tag in render html before write in response.

Comment: You could hide the columns with the images.

Comment: how to replace or hide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it and images are ignored.

```
protected void Export_to_Excel(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=PatientSearchReport.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xlsx";
        System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);  
        GridView1.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
        string html2 = Regex.Replace(stringWrite.ToString(), @"(<input type=""image""\/?[^>]+>)", @"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        html2 = Regex.Replace(html2, @"(<input class=""checkbox""\/?[^>]+>)", @"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        html2 = Regex.Replace(html2, @"(<a \/?[^>]+>)", @"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        Response.Write(html2.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
 protected void Export_to_Excel(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

GridView tmpGrid = new GridView();
// here bind this grid with same datasource which you have used for GridView1 

//System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=vault-extract-nsf.xls");
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xlsx";
System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
tmpGrid.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
Response.End();
}
```

Comment: check out my answer, I wrote that code and images are removed. Thanks for your concern :)